# Symfony2 ParamConverter not associated with @Annotation (cache must be cleared after any file change)

Tags: php, symfony, annotations

I have a Controller that uses Annotations for Route, Method, Template and ParamConverter.
If I make any change to the file (even a whitespace change or comment) on the next page load the following error occurs

```
Cannot import resource "/home/sites/MySite/src/Acme/Bundle/MyBundle/Controller/" from "/home/sites/MySite/app/config/routing.yml".

FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot import resource "/home/sites/MySite/src/Acme/Bundle/MyBundle/Controller/" from "/home/sites/MySite/app/config/routing.yml"

AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] The class "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter" is not annotated with @Annotation. Are you sure this class can be used as annotation? If so, then you need to add @Annotation to the _class_ doc comment of "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter". If it is indeed no annotation, then you need to add @IgnoreAnnotation("ParamConverter") to the _class_ doc comment of method Acme\Bundle\MyBundle\Controller\DefaultController::viewAction().
```

If I clear my cache, then it will work again, but only until I make another change, then it happens again.
It looks like it's hitting an issue when reading in the annotation info for config, but I can't understand why it works/doesn't work when the change isn't actually made to any annotation.

Comment: Can you show us your controller file?

Comment: Sure, have put into a gist here https://gist.github.com/catchamonkey/dbacc5752c89d1c9cf06

Comment: What version of Symfony are you using? Are you using eAccelerator?

Comment: I have the same problem after upgrading a project to Symfony 2.2. It only seems to happen in the prod environment, dev is okay. It works after clearing cache until I hit another controller with a ParamConverter on any action, not necessarily the action I'm hitting. After that, no action in any controller with ParamConverter works.

Comment: Not using eAccelerator, latest stable 2.2.0. Thanks tetranz, good to know it's not just me.

Comment: I added some more to my comment since you replied. No, not using eAccelerator but I am using APC. I'll try turning that off.

Comment: For me it's an issue in dev too, whenever I change the file in any way, even non-code changes.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be related to APC. It sounds like something to report to the Symfony project although it's kind of a hard one to define accurately. I've only used ParamConverter in a couple of places so easy to work around for now.

Comment: related -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843945/symfony2-1-semantical-error-the-class-annotation-is-not-annotated-with-anno

Comment: Reported: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7283

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah, it's a known bug, fixed in the FrameworkExtraBundle.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7283

And for now to get the latest, just change the requirement for that library to dev-master

```
"require": {
    ...
    "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
   ...
},
```

and run composer update

Comment: sensio/framework-extra-bundle v2.2.1 includes the fix, there's no need to use dev-master anymore, you can just use 2.2.* and get the latest tagged version.