# Doctrine annotation error in production server

Tags: symfony, annotations

I have an error in production server <strike>which doesn't occur in my localhost</strike>:

```
AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] 
The annotation "@Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route" in method My\Bundle\Controller\MyController::indexAction() does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

This error happened in local when I tryed to update some packages with *composer* and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247170/symfony2-paramconverter-not-associated-with-annotation-cache-must-be-cleared-a) didn't solve it, I had to reinstall symfony and upload everything again, **and is still happening**.

Cache has been cleared so I guess it's not a cache thing.

### AppKernel.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
        new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
        new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
        new MyProject\PanelBundle\MyProjectPanelBundle(),
        new MyProject\ProductBundle\MyProjectProductBundle(),
        new Front\SiteBundle\FrontSiteBundle(),
   );

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    }

    return $bundles;
}

public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
}
}
```

### Controller sample

And a sample of the anotattions in the controller which throws error:

```
/**
 * Lists all MyEnt entities.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="my_ent")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template("MyProjectPanelBundle:MyEnt:index.html.twig")
 */
public function indexAction($ident)
{
```

### App/config/routing.yml

```
front_site:
    resource: "@FrontSiteBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

MyProject_product:
    resource: "@MyProjectProductBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

MyProject_panel:
    resource: "@MyProjectPanelBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

Comment: maybe it's the php version?

Comment: can you share your controller and AppKernel.php code?

Comment: They are quite similar (well, I actually don't know what squeeze is), Local: 5.3.21 / Server: 5.3.3-7+squeeze15

Comment: @skafandri, added some code

Comment: did you import use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route; in controller ?

Comment: well, after deleting cache in local turns up that this is happening also in localhost, quite strange as it was working after reinstalling symfony and generating a whole new project

Comment: @Pawel, yes `use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;`

Comment: Which version of symfony2 ?

Comment: And one more, do you import controller in you routing file e.g:
blog:
    resource: "@MyBlogBundle/Controller"
    type:     annotation

Comment: Versions: symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.2.1), doctrine/annotations (v1.1). Will add app/config/routing.yml in original post

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.

Importing Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route class with require_once solved it.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/FrameworkExtraBundle/Configuration/Route.php';
```