# Symfony cache:clear Semantical Error with @Method Anotation

Tags: php, annotations

on my production build when I run:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

Symofny throws AnnotationExeption

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Cannot import resource "<path>/App/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php" from "<path>/App/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml". ([Semantical Error] The class "Method" is not annotated with @Annotation. Are you sure this class can be used as annotation? If so, then you need to add @Annotation to the _class_ doc comment of "Method". If it is indeed no annotation, then you need to add @IgnoreAnnotation("Method") to the _class_ doc comment of class @Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method.)  

[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[Semantical Error] The class "Method" is not annotated with    @Annotation. Are you sure this class can be used as annotation? If so, then you need to add @Annotation to the _class_ doc comment of "Method". If it is indeed no annotation, then you need to add @IgnoreAnnotation("Method") to the _class_ doc comment of class @Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method.
```

Not sure why, on my localcomputer it's working fine. And other projects using symfony annotations are working fine.

Packages versions: http://pastebin.com/71ZNrwSc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been solved with

```
"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
```

Same as this issue
[Symfony2 ParamConverter not associated with @Annotation (cache must be cleared after any file change)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247170/symfony2-paramconverter-not-associated-with-annotation-cache-must-be-cleared-a)

Related issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7283